# Firefox 11 Security Error? How to track it down

Tags: javascript, firefox, hookbox

Firefox 11 was pushed out the release channel this morning, and much to my chagrin one of the 3rd party libraries that I use in our Intranet (specifically, Hookbox) now triggers a "Security Error" in the console when it starts up. The library makes use of a lot of eval() madness for some reason (which I've never really been fond of) which I think is making this a little harder to track down.

Is there anything I'm not aware of in Firefox that will help me sort this out more quickly? The piece of code it's highlighting as causing the error really doesn't seem to make any sense. It would be helpful if I could know what specifically the type or cause of the Security Error is, for example.

I'm not really asking for help sorting out my specific issue, but I was hoping there was information available about Javascript Security Errors in Firefox in general.

Comment: You might want to take this to the [Hookbox Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/hookbox).

Comment: It turned out to be a WebSocket issue. I only arrived at the solution through a bunch of guesswork, though. My question still stands: is there a way to track these errors down more easily? For example, why didn't is say "Websocket Security Error" at the very least? And I'm still not sure exactly what about my Websockets is causing the error...

Comment: Well generally the first thing I would do would be to debug with non-minimized versions of all the libraries involved.

Comment: @Pointy I wasn't aware that the project was still active, the Github repo is pretty dead. I will check into it. But again, this is a more general question about tracking down this sort of issue in the future in Firefox regardless of the library...

Comment: It didn't say "Websocket Security Error" because there's only one kind of security error object in Gecko.  Usually the context in which the error is thrown will tell you which operation failed; this does involve debugging with unminified files.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the offending code in a try/catch block, then in the catch section you can either console.log() or console.dir() the error object passed into the catch section. For example:

```
try {
    security_error();
} catch(error_obj) {
    console.log(error_obj);
}
```

The error_obj's member variables should provide more info about the actual error.